# Putting files in "analyzer" dir in nupkg using new csproj format

Tags: nuget, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using new .csproj file format to pack NuGet package without using .nuspec file.

The problem is, it puts my dll in \lib\ where I need to put it \analyzers\

Who I do accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property that controls where the build output is placed is called `BuildOutputTargetFolder` which is defaulted to `lib` (or `tools` when `IsTool` is set to `true`):

```
<BuildOutputTargetFolder>analyzers</BuildOutputTargetFolder>
```

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the added `\netstandard1.3` added to this path? It prevents you from successfully packing a Roslyn analyzer which needs to follow the format `analyzers\dotnet\cs` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/analyzers-conventions#analyzers-path-format).

Comment: Ah, collected some workarounds in the open issue https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6793#issuecomment-513060540.